# Can I install Windows when a full encrypted Ubuntu disk is installed?

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, windows, encryption, disk

I am running a full-disk encrypted Ubuntu 12.10.

Can I install Windows alongside, adding it at the boot menu on this machine? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, encryption (LUKS) does not affect the ability to boot Windows as :

1. The boot partition is not encrypted.
2. The ability to boot windows is set in GRUB.

Are you having difficulty or just asking ?

FWIW: if you are installing Windows second, you will need to restore grub after installing windows. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, bodhi.zazen. This is great information. I was mostly confused about first steps. How do install Windows without wiping Ubuntu? Do I need to create a new partition first? Also, I hear that Windows can sometimes inadvertently write over the encrypted partition(s), as it thinks they are empty.

Comment: Yes you would create the partitions first. Resizing a LUKS is not so easy. Perhaps your best bet would be to start over, partition your hard drive, install windows, and then install Ubuntu. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions