# How can I encrypt the entire disk while installing Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, system-installation, encryption

I want to install Ubuntu with encryption.

- Will this damage my boot system?
- Will I need to remove my Windows system?
- What version of Ubuntu give me this feature?
- How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will [not affect your boot system](https://askubuntu.com/q/251701/62483), because *this will only encrypt the Ubuntu partition*. It won't encrypt the *boot* or *Windows* partitions.

So you can install Ubuntu alongside Windows or as unique OS without any problem.

**You don't need to remove any OS.** If you have enough free space in your disk, then you are done!

## For Ubuntu 12.10:

This feature can be enabled using any Live Edition (*LiveUSB*, *LiveCD*, *LiveDVD*).
During the installation of Ubuntu, in the *Installation Type* step you will see a similar window like this:

[image: screenshoot]

You have to activate the *Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for Security* option. Then Ubuntu will choice the [encryption type](https://askubuntu.com/q/228444/62483) automatically.

## [For Ubuntu 12.04 and older:](https://askubuntu.com/q/48766/62483)

You need to use the Ubuntu Alternate CD. You can download this selecting your version in [old-release](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/) or [release](http://releases.ubuntu.com/releases/) pages. Follow the instructions mentioned in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/48766/62483).